# Using dynamic "time" value

Tags: java

**Check out my app on [Google Play:](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aurum.mutify)**

> Code has been updated to use suggestions given by answer, however, still running into some problems...

I am using a BroadCast Receiver within a service to get metadata from Spotify (an external application). However, Spotify is unique in the fact that it sends the following intent-actions:

1. **metadatachanged** which contains the song's artist, track, **length**, etc.
2. **playbackstatechanged** which contains a boolean value for "playing" and an integer value for the current position in the song.

However, I have been running into some problems. I have written the following code:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

AudioManager am;
int positionInMs;
double eps = 5000;

String trackId = null;
String lastTrackId = null;
int lastPlayTime = 0;
int addSeconds = 0;
int trackLengthInSec = 0;
boolean playing = false;
boolean timerStarted = false;

void startTimer(){
    timerStarted = true;
    new Timer(true).scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(playing) {
                        if(lastTrackId == null) {

                            lastTrackId = trackId;

                        }else if (!lastTrackId.equals(trackId)) {

                            addSeconds = 1;
                            playing = true;
                            lastPlayTime = positionInMs;
                            // Track changed. Reset counter.

                        }else{

                            addSeconds++; // Increment counter.

                        }

                        checkMuteStatus(trackLengthInSec, lastPlayTime + addSeconds * 1000 // multiply by 1000 as we're counting in seconds
                        );
                    }

                    Log.e("-------:", "Last Play Time: " + String.valueOf(lastPlayTime));
                    Log.e("-------:", "Track Length: " + String.valueOf(trackLengthInSec));
                    Log.e("-------:", "Current Position: " + String.valueOf(lastPlayTime + addSeconds * 1000));

                }
            },
            1000, // Wait a second before first run
            1000 // Runs every second
    );
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    IntentFilter filter;
    filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.spotify.music.playbackstatechanged");
    filter.addAction("com.spotify.music.metadatachanged");
    filter.addAction("com.spotify.music.queuechanged");

    Notification notification = new Notification();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) throws NullPointerException {

        long timeSentInMs = intent.getLongExtra("timeSent", 0L);

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.METADATA_CHANGED)) {

            trackId = intent.getStringExtra("id");
            String artistName = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
            String albumName = intent.getStringExtra("album");
            String trackName = intent.getStringExtra("track");
            trackLengthInSec = intent.getIntExtra("length", 0);

            Log.e("STATUS:", trackName);
            Log.e("STATUS:", artistName);
            Log.e("STATUS:", albumName);
            Log.e("STATUS:", "TRACK LENGTH: " + String.valueOf(trackLengthInSec));
            Log.e("STATUS:", trackId);

            Log.e("STATUS:", "POSITION: " + String.valueOf(positionInMs));

            if(!timerStarted) {

                startTimer();

            }




            //---------------------- IF PAUSED OR SONG CHANGED---------------------

        } else if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED)) {

            playing = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);
            positionInMs = intent.getIntExtra("playbackPosition", 0);

            lastPlayTime = positionInMs;
            addSeconds = 0; // Reset counter as we've now got the current position.

            if(!timerStarted) {

                startTimer();

            }

        }

    }

};

    void checkMuteStatus(double trackLength, double currentTime) {

        if (Math.abs(trackLength - currentTime) < eps) {

            mute(am);
            Log.e("STATUS:", "MUTED");
            addSeconds = 0;
            lastPlayTime = 0;


        } else {

            unMute(am);
            Log.e("STATUS:", "NOT MUTED");


        }

    }




@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    Log.e("STATUS:", "In onDestroy");

    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


static final class BroadcastTypes {
    static final String SPOTIFY_PACKAGE = "com.spotify.music";
    static final String PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".playbackstatechanged";
    static final String METADATA_CHANGED = SPOTIFY_PACKAGE + ".metadatachanged";
}

public void mute(AudioManager audioManager){

    audioManager.setStreamMute(audioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, true);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);

}

public void unMute(AudioManager audioManager){

    audioManager.setStreamMute(audioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM,false);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, false);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
    audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, false);

}


}
```

Which all works perfectly in getting the data, etc.

Essentially I am attempting to mute a user's phone when the length of the song subtracted from the current playback time in the song is less than a certain number. This basically allows me to have the device muted when an ad is playing, and unmuted when a new song is started. The only problem I consistently come across is that **I can only access the current position in the song when the play state is changed. This essentially means that in order for my app to check whether it should mute the device, Spotify must first be paused so that the current playback time is updated.**

So my question is, how can I keep my current playback time up-to-date so that my muting functionality is able to work? Is there a way I can implement a "timer" of sorts which kicks in after I receive a value for the current playback time and then increments the time until next update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start a [timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) that executes every second when a song is played and use it to keep track of the elapsed seconds since.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) throws NullPointerException {
        long timeSentInMs = intent.getLongExtra("timeSent", 0L);
        String action = intent.getAction();     

        if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.METADATA_CHANGED)) {

             trackId = intent.getStringExtra("id");

             String artistName = intent.getStringExtra("artist");
             String albumName = intent.getStringExtra("album");
             String trackName = intent.getStringExtra("track");

             trackLengthInSec = intent.getIntExtra("length", 0);

             Log.e("STATUS:", trackName);
             Log.e("STATUS:", artistName);
             Log.e("STATUS:", albumName);
             Log.e("STATUS:", "TRACK LENGTH: " + String.valueOf(trackLengthInSec));
             Log.e("STATUS:", trackId);

             Log.e("STATUS:", "POSITION: " + String.valueOf(positionInMs));

             // the new track id is always updated just before the next song is played
             // so we can safely assume that the ad has finished playing and it's time to unmute
             unMute(am);

             // reset & resume the timer                 
             lastPlayTime = 0; 
             addSeconds = 0;
             currentlyAdPlaying = false;


             if(!timerStarted)
                startTimer();

            //---------------------- IF PAUSED OR SONG CHANGED---------------------

        } else if (action.equals(BroadcastTypes.PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            playing = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);
            positionInMs = intent.getIntExtra("playbackPosition", 0);

            // this is just needed to correct an eventually existing offset from the real time. 
            lastPlayTime = positionInMs;
            addSeconds = 0; // Reset counter as we've now got the current position.

            checkMuteStatus(trackLengthInSec, positionInMs);


        }
    }

};


String trackId = null;
String lastTrackId = null;
int lastPlayTime = 0;
int addSeconds = 0;
int trackLengthInSec = 0;
boolean playing = false;
boolean timerStarted = false;
boolean currentlyAdPlaying = true;

void startTimer(){   
    timerStarted = true;
    new Timer(true).scheduleAtFixedRate(
        new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                if(playing && !currentlyAdPlaying) {
                    if(lastTrackId == null)
                        lastTrackId = trackId;

                    if(lastTrackId != trackId){
                        lastTrackId = trackId;                      
                        addSeconds = 1; // Track changed. Reset counter.
                    } else {                            
                        addSeconds++; // Increment counter.
                    }

                    checkMuteStatus(
                        trackLengthInSec,
                        lastPlayTime + addSeconds * 1000
                    );
                }
            }
        }, 
        1000, // Wait a second before first run
        1000 // Runs every second
    );
}

void checkMuteStatus(double trackLength, double currentTime) {

    // trackLength is in seconds, but currentTime in MS. 
    // So we should be changing trackLength to MS as well, right?
    trackLength *= 1000;

    if (Math.abs(trackLength - currentTime) < eps) {

        mute(am);            
        Log.e("STATUS:", "MUTED");

        // pause the timer, for an ad is playing.
        currentlyAdPlaying = true;

    } else {

        unMute(am);
        Log.e("STATUS:", "NOT MUTED");


    }

}
```

Basically the timer runs every second (starting when an ad has finished playing) and then increments a counter as long as the song isn't paused. On reaching the end of the song the timer is suspended as an ad will be played next. Once the ad has finished playing, the timer is reset and resumed again. 
With this method you might be off by half a second or so, consider decreasing the timer interval if necessary to get a higher resolution (don't forget to adjust the multiplier though).

---

**Edit:**
The code above won't notice the user changing the track mid-song, as no broadcasts are sent on that occasion. A workaround might be to add a muting button using [notifications](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) (eg. in combination with [`FLAG_NO_CLEAR`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR) and [`FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT)).

Comment: how would I check if the user pauses the song, then pause the timer? I assume you would have to check the current time against the song's time to make sure the user is in fact pausing it rather than changing the song

Comment: Aren't you getting the current playback state by `playing = intent.getBooleanExtra("playing", false);`? So when the user pauses the song, `playing` should be false. Once that's the case the timer won't increment the counter any further, as the playing-flag is checked on every execution. If the user actually just changed the song, the new track-id would differ from the old one and the counter is reset as well - or is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: hmm I did not read carefully enough. Thanks for the advice and I will try this out asap

Comment: alright so I tried this out, and I do believe that it is the right approach. However, I have noticed that after having functioned correctly once (e.g. timer runs, mutes app, unmutes when song changes), it does not work again. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: basically the counter seems to not increment and reset after user changes the song

Comment: Can you check whether the `playing`-flag is set to true after the song is changed? And maybe you should reset the counter in the `METADATA_CHANGED` handler as well (I'm guessing the `PLAYBACK_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast might not always be sent when a new track starts playing, as playback isn't really paused).

Comment: So I tried setting the "playing" flag to true programmatically if the track id's don't match up (if song is changed), but the counter still does not increment after user goes to next song. However, it does work the first time.

Comment: I just went through the timer code again and it seems I had a stupid bug in it; I forgot to update the `lastTrackId` variable once the track has changed. Sorry for that. See my edit for the corrected version. Does it work now?

Comment: things are still not working. It seems that when an ad is playing OR paused, the "playing" action is kept at true, and the timer continues to run. In order for the ad muting function to work correctly, I need to be able to differentiate between an ad playing and a regular track playing. Thus, when an ad is playing, the timer should not increment until the next trackID change

Comment: So `playing` is set to true _even with the ad paused_? Do you get any broadcast/event when the ad has finished playing? At which point is the new track id updated (prior to / after playing the ad)?

Comment: so the new track id is always updated just before the next song is played, so yes this would be after the ad finishes. And yes "playing" is kept at true even when the ad is paused

Comment: OK right, next attempt. I've edited my answer again, chances are it'll work this time...

Comment: this works perfectly. The only other problematic scenario i've noticed is when the user is in the middle of a song, but then he/she skips INTO an ad rather than a song.

Comment: Are there any broadcasts/events that get fired if the user skips a song? (Does Spotify make any other broadcasts?) I don't see how it would be possible to notify your app about the user having cancelled the song automatically, if there aren't any events you can use. 
Is having the user manually tapping an entry in the notification area an option?

Comment: I guess letting the user manually mute Spotify by clicking the notification would work